# How to display GPX track with scalar values in leaflet?

Tags: python, leaflet, gpx, color-mapping

I know how to write js code to display data from a gpx file in leaflet:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/230C3.png)

I know how to extract data from this gpx file to convert it to a NumPy array and display track as points with elevation as scalar values, still in js code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwlMW.png)

But I don't know how to display data from gpx file as line in first image but colored as in second image.

How could I do that?

TIA

But I don't know how to display data from gpx file as line in first image but colored with a colormap as in second image.

How could I do that?